# Is it possible to set a certain amount of scroll?

Tags: javascript

I've made a draggable element inside a scrollable container. When I drag the element to a position where it overflows the container, I want to increase the amount of scroll in that direction. I could not find anything on setting the scroll amount. Any help would be appreciated.

BTW: I am using plain Javascript.

Comment: Perhaps [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm thinking he wants the scrollHeight to increase.  You just have to increase the `height` of the html element with overflow: auto/scroll, when scrollWidth or scrollHeight become larger than the clientwidth and height

Comment: Like @user120242 said, the `height` and `width` of the element determine the scrollable area. If you have some code for us to review that would help!

Comment: @ztrat4dkyle, I found the solution to my answer with your help. I just added a new <div> that contains the draggable elements and is inside of my draggable container. Changing any height and width in the new <div> allows me to add how much horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous hierarchy of elements was something like this:

```
<scrollable-container>
  <draggable>
```

My hierarchy is now this:

```
<scrollable-container>
  <new-div>
    <draggable>
```

By adjusting the new-div's height and width, it changes the amount of scroll in the scroll container. This now allows me to give a certain amount of scroll.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as a solution.  Feel free to add more information to show how you were able to adjust the height and width, as well as references to whoever helped you.